Как получить доступ к localStorage при NetworkError?
Есть код, который загружает страницу при NetworkError:
const url = window.location.href;

var that = new XMLHttpRequest();
that.open('GET', url, false);
try {
  that.send();
} catch(exception) {
  if(exception.name == 'NetworkError'){
   alert('There was a network error.');
   document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(url));
}
}


Но он не работает, т.к. при ошибке подключения localStorage почему-то становится пустым. Как это обойти? Заранее спасибо.

А без ошибки там что то есть? В вашем коде нет "обнуления" localStorage, так же нет и его создания

Потому что localStorage для каждого сайта свой, не открыли сайт— не получили localStorage

@SwaD есть, без проверки на ошибку всё работает. Насчёт обнуления - я его не предусматривал, переменные попросту "исчезают" во время ошибки

@DaniilLoban знаю, что свой, я открывал один и тот же сайт с интернетом и без.

Если это не PWA — прогрессивное веб приложение, не поможет, для браузера это будет разным.

Судя по коду, когда ошибки нет, вы не лезете в локалсторадж. Почему вы решили, что данные пропадают?

@SwaD я заходил в хранилище через браузер и переменных уже не было. Появились они снова только при включении интернета.

В catch добавьте первой строкой вывод в консоль переменной url и значения из localStoarage. Так же попробуйте закомментировать строку с изменение html, возможно при изменении всего html, а не body, браузер считает, что это другой сайт и убирает все связаанные с ним объекты.

@SwaD попробовал, теперь если интернет есть - он выводит url в консоль, а если нету - не выводит. Думаю тут проблема в том, что url меняется на about:neterror?e=dnsNotFound, а адреса about неприкосновенны расширениями.

Попробуйте добавить в код that.onerror = function(error) { а сюда вставить ваши действия из блока catch }.
